# Mongoose Schema Not Defined when Route is included in different file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

To clean up my code, I decided to put all of my schemas and routes into different files in my directory, and require them in my app.js.  Each Schema corresponds to each route.  For all but one of my routes, I have gotten this to work, but for one specific one, I cannot find out why I am getting it as undefined.

Here is the code I have in my app.js (the main file)

```
// Schemas
const Transaction = require ("./models/transaction");
User              = require ("./models/user");
Ticket            = require ("./models/ticket");
Job               = require ("./models/job");
Client            = require ("./models/client");

// Routes
require("./routes/users")(app);
require("./routes/tickets")(app);
require("./routes/clients")(app);
require("./routes/jobs")(app);
require("./routes/transactions")(app);
```

All of these work, except for my transaction route.
Here is its schema:

```
// =======================Transaction Schema "./models/transaction"

var transactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    job: String,
    client: String,
    deposited_by_user: String,
    transaction_info:{
        amount: mongoose.Decimal128,
        method: String,
        receipt_number: String,
        date: {type: Date}
    },
    billing_address: {
        street: String,
        city: String,
        state: String,
        zip: String
    },
    notes: String,
    date_added: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Transaction", transactionSchema);
```

And its route:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    // =======================Transaction  "./routes/transactions"

// index
app.get("/transactions", function(req, res){
    Transaction.find({}, function(err, transactions){    // It is at this line where it is telling me that "Transaction" is undefined.  However, with this code pasted into the app.js exactly the same as it is here, it works fine.
        if(err){
            console.log("error")
        } else {                                        
            for (let i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++){
                transactions[i]["transaction_info"]["new_amount"] = numberWithCommas(transactions[i]["transaction_info"]["amount"]);
            }
            res.render("transactions", {transactions: transactions});
        }
    });
});

// new
app.get("/transactions/add", async function(req, res){
 let endCollections = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < collections.length; i++){
        await collections[i].find({}, function(err, foundCollection){ 
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                endCollections[i] = foundCollection;                
            }
        });
    }
    res.render("add_transaction", {users: endCollections[0], clients: endCollections[2], jobs: endCollections[3]}); 
});

// show
app.get("/transactions/:id", function(req, res){
    Transaction.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundTransaction){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //  Redirect
            let price = numberWithCommas(foundTransaction["transaction_info"]["amount"]);
            res.render("transaction", {transaction: foundTransaction, price: price});
        }
    });
});

// edit
app.get("/transactions/:id/edit", function(req, res){
    Transaction.findById(req.params.id, async function(err, foundTransaction){
        if (err){
            console.log("error")
        } else {
            let endCollections = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < collections.length; i++){
                await collections[i].find({}, function(err, foundCollection){ 
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        endCollections[i] = foundCollection;                
                    }
                });
            }       
            let deposit_date = foundTransaction["transaction_info"]["date"];
            deposit_date = moment(deposit_date).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
            res.render("edit_transaction", {transaction: foundTransaction, users: endCollections[0], clients: endCollections[2], jobs: endCollections[3], deposit_date: deposit_date});
        }
    });
});

// create
app.post("/transactions", function(req, res){ 
//  Create Transaction
    Transaction.create(req.body.transaction, function(err, newTransaction){
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            //  Redirect
            res.redirect("/transactions");
        }
    });
});

// update
app.put("/transactions/:id", function(req, res){ 
//  Update transaction
    Transaction.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.transaction, function(err, updatedTransaction){
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            //  Redirect
            res.redirect("/transactions/" + req.params.id);
        }
    });
});

// delete
app.delete("/transactions/:id", function(req, res){ 
//  Delete job
    Job.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err, deletedTransaction){
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            //  Redirect
            res.redirect("/transactions");
        }
    });
});

}
```

I do not believe the Schema is the problem because when I paste the Transaction route code directly into my app.js file, character for character, it works fine.  However, with it split (and the code stays exactly the same in the transactions.js file) I am getting the error when I load the page that "Transaction is undefined" at the part of my code that starts with Transaction.find

Overall, I cannot understand why when the route is in the app.js file, it works just fine, but when it is in a separate file, the Transaction variable is considered undefined; this is all despite it being modeled exactely the same as my other routes and schemas.  Is there something here I am not seeing?  Thanks.

Comment: Does any one of your schema files require other schemas? Please include the `require` statements for each of your file. I suspect you have circular/cyclic dependency structure

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, you are correct, I needed to require the files in each of the routes, that fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

1) 
Instead of:

```
app.get("/transactions", function(req, res){
.
.
app.get("/transactions/:id", function(req, res){
```

Maybe just:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
.
.
app.get("/:id", function(req, res){
```

and so on?

2)

```
Transaction.find({}, function(err, transactions){
```

Instead of {} try ()

```
Transaction.find((), function(err, transactions){
```

It looks as you are passing one empty object

Comment: So, in the app.js file I already have a "/" route for the main page.  And the thing is, for all of the other routes, clients, jobs, ect. I have it set as app.get("/clients", function(req, res { and those work just fine.

Comment: OK, please check the answer 2

Comment: Thank you for the help with the second answer.  Unfortunately when I change the code, it is telling me that the '(' is an unexpected token, I am pretty sure I need to use {}.  The object should not be undefined, like I said, it works when the code is in the main J's file, but not when it is in a separate file for some reason.

Comment: I can confirm that the "Transaction" variable can be used in my main app.js file.  It is when I try to pass it into the route file that it becomes undefined.